# (PHP) How to check column A and column B's value that has same ID simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have imported my csv file into mysql database.

The table contains information about country and it has 8 fields.

It look like this:

```
CountryName | Monarchy | IntoSpace | Guns | Exist
America          NO         YES      YES     YES
Canada           NO         YES      YES     YES
Japan            YES        YES       NO     YES
Russia           NO         YES      YES     YES
Poland           NO         NO        NO     YES
RomanEnpire      YES        NO        NO     NO
```

So, I want people who visits my website to chose one of these country.
After that, it will communicate with the database.

I basically want to get the value of 1 row (If that's poland, that's going to be, 
Poland, No, No, No, No,)and execute with my php code.

But I can't figure out how I could do that.

Any tips?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Very likely, with a DB query. What is your attempt to do this task? Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I basically want to make a website where people could select a country from the droplist and then see some nice tips about them.

Comment: This is quite broad, but if you only need one result, try reading about `PDO`'s [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) or `MySqli`'s [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot Swellar! I will try it out.

Comment: And I'm not sure if my edit is correct, so you can roll it back anytime if it is wrong indeed

Comment: One more thing, you need to choose only one of either [**`PDO`**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**`MySQLi`**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't exactly get your question(Be more specific).
But this might help you -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE country='poland'";
// $conn = your connection to database
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$array = $result->fetch_assoc();
//You got an array containing all data
$country = $array['country'];
$monarchy = $array['monarchy'];
 // you can get them all.
echo $monarchy;
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: Thanks a lot Goyal. You saved my day :)